# How to assassinate Andre

Tags: saints-row-the-third

I'm having trouble getting Andre to spawn in Espina during his Assassination sidequest. Since I'm in the late game, the Morningstar are gone, so even if I manage to find/kill the hos, I can't get the Morningstar star/threat level up. But if I manage to get the threat level up, then no pedestrians/hos spawn in that area. It's a catch-22.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The secret to this is to first kill hos in Espina (e.g., three), then start the nearby trafficking activity. By the time you leave the cul-de-sac, your gang/star threat level will be up and Morningstar will spawn. Now I believe Andre spawned during this activity for me, but if he doesn't show by the time you're out on the main Espina street, you can exit the activity with the Morningstar cars nearby and quickly kill them to raise your threat level outside of the activity. This, in combination with the hos killed before, should spawn Andre.